# How to create Deployment package for iOS using Marmalade

Tags: ios, marmalade

I am using Windows7 and Marmalade 5.1.10. I tried to create deployment package for iOS but it is giving error of certificate not found at particular location. I checked in that location and there is one .cer file presents. I installed that certificate under trusted root authorities store. Still I am getting same error. Then I copied that and renamed .cer file to AppleWWDRCA.cer file as per given in error message. After that it is giving me error:

> "Signing error: Can't find your developer signing private key at C:\Marmalade\5.1\s3e\deploy\plugins\iphone\certificates\developer_identity.key".

Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Note that I dont have Apple ID created for iOS developper.

Please share your input on this.

What if I just want to test with iPhone simuulator? I tried following:
I created my simple demo application. Then I created package for iPhone on my Windows PC. While creating package I selected option "Do Not Sign". I got success with that. Then I transfered .app to my MacMini. I copied .app to XCode in appropriate folder of Application. Then I started iPhone Simulator and I can see my application. But when I click on that it is not opening.

So now let me know what can be issue. Is it due to certificate issue or due to selected option "Do Not Sign"?

Please treat this as little bit urgent.

Thank you very much in advance for your inputs.

Regards,
Premal Panchal

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed description of how to create the necessary certificate files in the Marmalade Documentation help file, installed as part of the SDK.  You can find it here:-

Marmalade->Platform Guides->iOS Guide (for iPhone, iPad, iPod)->iOS Requirements and Setup Guide

When you say you don't have an Apple ID created for iOS Developer do you mean you haven't signed up to the iOS Developer Program?  If so, then you won't be able to generate a signed build at all.

Regarding testing with the iPhone simulator, I don't think that this is possible.  If it is possible you will probably need to have a signed app.  I believe the reason XCode can run in the iPhone Simulator even without valid developer certificates is that it is doing it's own signing of the generated app behind the scenes.

Comment: I have read documentation and followed that. I have registered as Developer program. Now I am facing some other issue. You can check my new post about that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816517/error-in-getting-provisioning-certificate-for-ios-development