# Error in getting provisioning certificate for iOS development

Tags: ios, marmalade

I want to test my iOS application on iPad. For this I have created developer certificate,App ID and Device ID on Apple Portal. After that I have created Provisioning profile on portal.It is activated and I can see download button. When I click on download it is giving me error of Failed Download.

Note that for signing and creating .csr I have used Marmalade signing tool as I am developing applicaton using Marmalade. Also I am using Windows 7 for development.

Please let me know what can be issue.

Regards,
Premal

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty old question, but another developer might fall in the same error. 
The basic steps you need are:

- generating a .csr file, using Marmalade Code Sign Request tool
- Inside Apple developer panel, create two certificates (.cer): One for development, one for distribution
- register your iOS device with its UDID in the Apple Developer panel
- Also in Apple Developer panel, create two provisioning profiles (.mobileprovision): One for development, one for distribution, associated to your certificate (.cer), and your devices (UDID).
- Inside Marmalade's .mkb file, include the recently created .mobileprovision like this:

  ```
  iphone-provisioning-profile='data/myprofile.mobileprovision'
  ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a browser issue? Just in case, check out this tutorial which walks you through the complete iOS signing and deployment using Marmalade http://www.drmop.com/index.php/2011/12/10/marmalade-sdk-tutorial-apple-iphone-and-ipad-deployment-and-submissions/. If you follow this then you should have no problems.